# Efficient way to compare data between the sql database and a json response

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, codeigniter

I have a codeigniter server that responds with data like this:

```
{
    success: true,
    {
        data: {
                  {
                       name: 'Elizabeth Gusto',
                       title: 'Marketing/sales'
                  },

                  {
                       name: 'Martin Pablo',
                       title: 'Field Sales'
                  },

                  {
                       name: 'Brian Carey',
                       title: 'In House I.T.'
                  },
                  ...
              }
      }
}
```

I take this data and save directly into an sql database in an app that i'm working on, with columns:

`ID, Name, Title,...`

ID is just a primary key, and is set to `AUTO INCREMENT`

> Note: I use the sqflite plugin in flutter to save data. But the working is exactly like the SQL queries.

How do I compare all the data I received from the server with data available in the sql database? i.e. Do the server's response matches to what i have stored in sql?

Answer (score 1):

First, you should define what identifies an incoming record. In your example, the ID is not part of the incoming values, so you obviously can't use it.

- E.g. you could define that just the name identifies a record. Then you can query the database for such a record and compare all the remaining fields.
- Or you could define that all attributes identify a record and you can just look it up by matching all the data in your query.

It depends on your requirements what to do next. E.g. update found entries or create new entries or you might even want to delete old records. But you should get the idea.

To speed things up, you should create a compound database index (possibly using multiple columns) for the columns to be searched (the ones that identify a record).

To further speed things up and reduce the amount of round-trips between your database and your program, make use of prepared statements and batched statements.